Takeout for "Location History" has only one file "Encrypted Backups.txt" that reads "You have encrypted Timeline backups stored on Google servers"
After migrating to mobile-only Google Maps Timeline I wanted to download its data so I went on my phone through the steps of exporting it via Google Takeout. Unfortunately, this didn't produce the expected result as the ZIP file that I received contains for Google Maps only a file called Encrypted Backups.txt with a single sentence in it saying:

You have encrypted Timeline backups stored on Google servers.

I then tried to disable the encryption, but could not find any settings.
The Timeline Takeout is pretty useless when it doesn't provide any real data.
Does anyone know what can be done to export it?

This may be related to Timeline data moving to mobile. See the section "Import your Timeline data from a backup" on Update Google Maps to use Timeline on your device

Can you [edit] your question to include whether or not you've migrated your data to mobile yet?

@Blindspots: done!

I have exactly the same issue. I successfully downloaded a limited version of my timeline from my device, via the obscure device route "Device ​Settings > Location > Location Services > Timeline > Export Timeline data". But this gives 1 location reading per minute, compared to updates that were every 2-20sec in the data I previously downloaded via Google Takeout.

is this new update frequency documented/expected @effgee?


After migrating to mobile-only Google Maps Timeline I wanted to download its data so I went on my phone through the steps of exporting it via Google Takeout.

You have no data to download
Google Maps location history (timeline) used to provide a comprehensive view of all saved location history associated with your Google account from any device.
The model is changing and location history will no longer be stored in Google accounts but instead on the specific device that generates it.
Google has provided a deadline of Dec 8, 2024 for users to migrate their existing location data to their preferred smartphone or risk losing it permanently.
Since you have already migrated your data from your Google account to your mobile device, there is nothing left to download.
Google Takeout
Google Takeout (aka "Download Your Data"), is an online Google account (not device) tool that allows users to download Google account data including location history if it hasn't already been migrated to a mobile device.

There is only one version of Takeout, regardless if accessed from your desktop or mobile, and once a user has performed the Timeline data migration to a mobile device, their location history, as well as any records detailing edits, deletions, settings, or other location history-related data, is no longer in their Google account and, as a result, no longer available to be downloaded

"I went on my phone through the steps of exporting it via Google Takeout...   ...this didn't produce the expected result...   ...only a file...   ...with a single sentence in it"

Before migration, your location data from Takeout would have included a combination of JSON and CSV files.

Moving forward, Takeout downloads no longer include the data removed from your account but might include a text file indicating that one or more encrypted Timeline backups exist on Google's servers.

Timeline encrypted backup location?
Google allows you to configure your mobile device backup to include Timeline data, in much the same way it does for other applications such as your SMS messages.
Mobile device backups are both encrypted and hidden, and the space used counts against your Google storage quota.
The backups are not intended to be directly accessed by users however there are likely 3rd party tools that can provide direct access to them.
Timeline has an Import Tool
Google has provided the ability to [import/restore a Timeline backup] to your mobile device. The target can be the original device that created the backup or a different one.
Important: Google doesn't indicate what happens to pre-existing data on the target device as a result of the import.  Presumably, any existing Timeline data on the device is overwritten rather than being merged, but this needs to be confirmed.

Import Timeline data from a backup
To move an existing backup to a different device or import your Timeline on a new device,
you can import your Timeline data from a backup:

On your Android phone, open the Google Maps app .
Tap your profile picture or initial  and then Your Timeline.
At the upper right, tap the cloud 
From the "Your backups" section, select a device.
Tap More  and then Import.
On the "Import Timeline from backup" screen, tap Import.


Additional Resources

Google Takeout
Update Google Maps to use Timeline on your device
Manage your Timeline data
Turn on backup on your device


I'll give you +1 for describing what Google has done (although I was aware of that), however, I cannot accept this answer as it doesn't provide a solution or doesn't answer why the Google Takeout exports empty files for the Timeline and also doesn't explain how to get to the file storing the actual routes.

Yeah, as you can see I've originally posted this question on Super User as I thought it's better suited there as there might be some "hacking around" necessary, but unfortunatelly mods have moved it to here. I'm not happy with this decision either.

The [su] migration was because of "Google Maps Timeline."  If the original Q included the subsequent updates (completed data migration to mobile) and that community picked up on that and understood the implications, it might have been migrated to [android.se]. To be a [su] question it'd need to focus on a desktop app problem like extracting data from a locally-saved cloud backup, but I think [android.se] makes sense to ensure you get it in front of the right experts. The current version of the Q will be helpful to web apps users seeking clarification about the recent changes.

@your-majesty I have revised my answer after re-reading your comments. I hope it is now more clear.
